# vscode chooses unusual option for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

While using the latest version of Visual Studio Code I am editing a JavaScript file and often want to log output to the console. I created a user snippet to make this easier to autocomplete but I've found that the default option I get in my autocomplete is the red highlighted option below (instead of the green which is *my* snippet):

[image]

I'm wondering two things:

1. Where is this "non-standard" autocomplete coming from? Can I remove it?
2. How does vscode determine which of the matches will be the default, and can I influence it to choose my snippets first?

Comment: I have the same problem. Temporarily fell back to version 1.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"` to your configuration to ensure snippets are always sorted on top

Comment: Excellent, but I wonder why in the new version that has changed. Prior to version 1.8 snippets worked as they should.

Comment: Yeah, we have been exploring to remember and pre-select the suggestion that has been inserted most recently. You can tweak that via `"editor.suggestSelection"`