# Visual Studio Code Order In AutoCompletion

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, panic

I recently switched to Visual Studio Code and I love it! It starts so quickly andI just enjoy the open source environment more than Visual Studio. But there's one problem that I have encountered that bothers me more than it should.

Before I could if I wanted to autocomplete the syntax for an if statement I'd just be able to type in "if" and touble tap tab, but now the autocompletion IntelliSense things pop up in the wrong order:

[image]

The red box is the wrong one that gets displayed first and the green box is the one I want at the top. My question is if there's a way to configure it so that I get that statement at the top. It's the same with for-loops, foreach-loops and pretty much every other autocompletion that I want to use.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Create snippet (or edit) <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd> `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`
2. settings (<kbd>ctrl+,</kbd>)

```js
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Yesterday, Johannes Rieken, updated this in comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/42107910/6011421

Comment: Well, that's a different feature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304160/over-ride-default-snippet-prefix-in-vs-code

Comment: Is there a way to move to the top only one specific snippet (for example log -> console.log() for javascript) just leaving all the other snippets in default position?