# Over-ride Default Snippet Prefix in VS Code

Tags: json, editor, code-snippets, visual-studio-code

I am writing some JavaScript snippets for VS Code, and when I add the one for an event listener, there are a number of pre-defined prefix allocations relating to other pieces of code. I would like to use "ael" as the prefix prompt for this snippet, but that defaults to an alert command (this is particularly frustrating because the first 3 letters of alert are actually "ale"), anyway, is there a way of over-riding the default behaviour?

In the code below if I change the `prefix` to "ttt", and subsequently type "ttt", the snippet works, when I use "ael" it doesn't.

How do I over-ride this?

SNIPPET

```
"ael": {
    "prefix": "ael",
    "body": [
        "addEventListener(\"\t$1\", function(){",
        "\t$2",
        "}, false);"
    ],
    "description": "Add an Event Listener",
}
```

[image]

Comment: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",` ?

Comment: @Alex Where will this go?

Comment: user settings ?

Comment: No, sadly that didn't work

Comment: Then give more details. Logically `"ael"` should overwrite `alert` keyword. Add a screenshot.

Comment: screenshot added.  Even when i scroll down the list to either of the default addEventListener options it still doesn't use my one. Unless I change the prefix to something like the "ttt" as mentioned, which has no preset values. Also i should mention i am not running any JS extentions either.  This is a fresh install of VS code

Answer (score 3):

It's a part of the latest update: [1.19 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_smarter-intellisense)

When you accept a suggestion it remembers and jumps to the thing that you previously accepted. Here is the issue about controlling this feature: [#41060](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41060)

Since vscode **1.20** there is an option to disable or modify this behavior:

`"editor.suggestSelection"`

`"first"` - as it was before (no rememering, no preselecting)

`"recentlyUsed"` - select the previously used item

`"recentlyUsedByPrefix"` - select items based on prefixes you have used

Comment: Thanks. I'll read that properly when I'm home.  The current feature is the single most stupid thing I've seen in a code editor since the time Brackets decided to not allow you to remove all folders from the workspace area so you always had to have one in there even if you weren't using it.  Perhaps I'll go back to Atom.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what is going on with you, then you do not need to scroll through the list. When you type `ael`, your snippet is already selected in the dropdown list (judging by the screenshot). You just need to press `Enter` or `Tab` after that.

#### Several prefixes in the snippet

In addition, you can add additional prefixes for ease of use in different situations, for example, like this:

```json
    "addEventListener": {
        "prefix": ["ael", "addEventListener"],
        "body": [
            "addEventListener(\"${1:event}\", (${2:e}) => {",
            "\t$0",
            "}, false);"
        ],
        "description": "Add an Event Listener",
    }
```

After that, if you enter, for example, `add` or even `adli` in the `javascript` file, the list shown below will appear.
[image: addEventListener dropdown list]
In it, you will need to move a few steps down to the `addEventListener` line and also press `Enter` or `Tab`, after which the editor will insert the code from the snippet, select the first placeholder (`$1`), which in this case contains the name of the event. Next, you can edit it, press `Tab` to move to the second placeholder (`$2`), change the input parameter of the function, and then press `Tab` again to move to the body of the function (`$0` - last placeholder).

#### Suggest selection

And yes, as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5590193) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305768/5589126), you can use `editor.suggestSelection` setting to change the behavior of the pre-selection in the dropdown. As described on [code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_suggestion-selection):

> - `first` - Always select the top list item.
> - `recentlyUsed` - (default) The previously used item is selected unless a prefix (type to select) selects a different item.
> - `recentlyUsedByPrefix` - Select items based on previous prefixes that have completed those suggestions.
>
> "Type to select" means that the current prefix (roughly the text left of the cursor) is used to filter and sort suggestions. When this happens and when its result differs from the result of `recentlyUsed` it will be given precedence.
>
> When using the last option, `recentlyUsedByPrefix`, VS Code remembers which item was selected for a specific prefix (partial text). For example, if you typed `co` and then selected `console`, the next time you typed `co`, the suggestion `console` would be pre-selected. This lets you quickly map various prefixes to different suggestions, for example `co` -> `console` and `con` -> `const`.

#### Snippets in suggestions

As [code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_snippets-in-suggestions) notes:
By default, VS Code shows snippets and completion proposals in one widget. You can control the behavior with the `editor.snippetSuggestions` setting. Available values for it:

- `none` - remove snippets from the suggestions widget
- `top` - place snippets at the top
- `bottom` - place snippets at the bottom
- `inline` - (default) show snippet suggestions with other suggestions ordered alphabetically