# VSCode CompletionItems are showing at the bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a vscode extension that adds completionItems so that they show up in the autocomplete dialog.
But the issue is, completionitems (methods) I've added, show up at the bottom of the list.
Global identifiers show up on the top of the list.

Is there a way to change/override this behavior ?

[image: global identifiers show up before completionItems (methods)]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43857693/863110) can help or [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

Comment: @MoshFeu - Tried them and they do not work.